# How to run que-rails in aws elastic-beanstalk in async with puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I am using [que gem](https://github.com/chanks/que-rails) for sending emails asynchronously. I am using elastic-beanstalk and puma as the server. As per the puma's documentation I find out that there are two ways to provide custom config to the puma (which i have tried)

1. putting config/puma.rb
2. putting config/puma/production.rb

what i want to [achieve is this](https://github.com/chanks/que-rails#forking-servers). I did not find any way to override the on_worker_boot apart from this. 
**What else I have tried -**
Writing custom script (.ebextensions) to kill existing process with que:work and with starting again on post load environment

```
files:
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_que.sh":
mode: "000755"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  set -xe
  # Loading environment data
  EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)
  EB_SUPPORT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir)
  EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user)
  EB_APP_CURRENT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir)

  . $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/envvars
  . $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh

  cd $EB_APP_CURRENT_DIR

  su -s /bin/bash -c "pkill -f que:work" $EB_APP_USER

  echo 'REAPED que:work processes.'

  su -s /bin/bash -c "bundle exec rake que:work" $EB_APP_USER
```

But no luck so far.. 
Are there any other alternatives to set the *Que.mode = :async* after puma starts?